# How do I display a XAML format image from a Assets folder?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, uwp-xaml

I am trying to display an XAML formatted image.  The image lives in my Assets folder and the Build Action is set to content.

I would like to retrieve the image, but everything I've tried has failed including a ContentControl, Button and Image. Instead of showing the image, it shows the image's path name as text.

```
  <ContentControl Content="Assets/Logos/ups.xaml" Width="100" Height="100"/>
```

Comment: What platform(s) are you on?

Comment: I am using UWP and will port to Xamarin later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do that. Xaml has to be loaded as a component / visual tree.

Look into [XamlReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader)

Maybe you can create your own custom control that reads `Uri` source and processes the contents. Or maybe someone out there has already created such control.

```
<MyCustomXamlControl Source="Assets/Logos/ups.xaml" Width="100" Height="100"/>
```

And code looks like this:

```
private async void OnSourceChanged(Uri source)
{
    var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(source);

    string xaml;

    using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream.AsStream()))
    {
        xaml = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    this.Content = XamlReader.Load(xaml);
}
```

**Note:** I haven't tested the above. This is just a quick sample I put together, please don't judge quality :) Try fiddling around to figure out how to load file to `string` and give it to `XamlReader`.

Comment: I'm surprised at the effort required to display a native format. I would expect at least an adapter you can assign to Source that reads the XML like so:   <ContentControl Content=XmlReader("Assets/Logos/ups.xaml") Width="100" Height="100"/>

Comment: Why are you surprised? This is Microsoft.

Comment: You can create a `UserControl` instead of a stand-alone XAML file. That does the same thing when it's instantiated. The constructor calls `InitializeComponent()` which loads up the XAML using `XamlReader`

Comment: Curious as to the syntax.  I guess it would be static.  In the UWP samples, MS could have used XAML instead of PNG for the splash and logo screens.  It would have showed off how to use a single image to create multiple sizes using less space.

Comment: XAML allows you to enter all sorts of elements outside the scope of a flattened image. Form elements such as `TextBox` and `ComboBox`, what should the OS do when you provide a splash screen with user input?